# Como faço para deixar um campo de preenchimento obrigatório?

Tags: c#, console

Estou montando uma aplicação de gerenciamento de aniversarios(Consoleapp) p/ faculdade... Gostaria de saber como faço para deixar obrigatório a entrada dos campos Nome/Sobrenome/CPF/dataNascimento quando o usuário for adicionar uma nova pessoa? Ah e gostaria de saber como por o CPF para ter obrigatoriamente 11 caracteres?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CSharpUltimateASS;

namespace CSharpUltimateASS
{
    public class Pessoa
    {
        public string _nome;
        public string _sobrenome;
        public string _CPF;
        public DateTime _dataNascimento;

        public Pessoa(string nome, string sobrenome, string CPF, DateTime dataNascimento)
        {
            _nome = nome;
            _sobrenome = sobrenome;
            _CPF = CPF;
            _dataNascimento = dataNascimento;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Faça um validador para cpf,  vc pode procurar que tem vários exemplos.  Vc pode usar também o Fluent Validation para validar sua classe

Comment: Qual é o objetivo do exercío? Isso influência na abordagem que a gente pode recomendar. Obs.: aqueles atributos iniciados com "_" não deveriam ser privados?

Comment: Bom, já que você não tem um construtor padrão, esses campos já são obrigatórios na classe, o que na verdade acho que você está querendo é verificar se os parametros do construtor possuem valores válidos. Você pode fazer um método Factory que te devolve a instancia do objeto apenas caso os parametros estejam preenchidos corretamente e deixar esse construtor que você fez privado, forçando o programador a acessar o método Factory

Comment: Porém, se seu objetivo é fazer um validador para o usuário, você pode também usar o conceito que falei de Factory, porém retornando uma lista com mensagens a ser apresentadas ao usuário em caso de algum campo não estar correto. A implementação disso pode ser um pouco sofisticada demais para o escopo do seu exercício no entanto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para manter a solução disso de forma que atenda o escopo do seu exercício, eu fiz essas alterações no seu código, porém fiz de uma forma que fique simples o suficiente para o seu professor não achar ruim e claro, para você aprender também.

Como eu não sei até onde seu professor já te ensinou, eu não vou modificar nada na sua classe, eu acredito que o objetivo de fazer o "_" antes dos nomes é para criar propriedades públicas usando variáveis privadas, porém vou deixar seu código assim mesmo.

Estou criando aqui um método estático que vai te retornar uma instância da classe Pessoa, apenas se todos os campos estiverem validados. Caso contrário, vai te retornar `null`

Perceba que coloquei o construtor como `private` assim o programador é obrigado a chamar o método `GetInstancia`

```
public class Pessoa
{
    public string _nome;
    public string _sobrenome;
    public string _CPF;
    public DateTime _dataNascimento;

    private Pessoa(string nome, string sobrenome, string CPF, DateTime dataNascimento)
    {
        _nome = nome;
        _sobrenome = sobrenome;
        _CPF = CPF;
        _dataNascimento = dataNascimento;
    }

    public static Pessoa GetInstancia(string nome, string sobrenome, string CPF, DateTime dataNascimento)
    {
        bool construir = true;

        if (nome == "")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("O nome é obrigatório.");
            construir = false;
        }

        if (sobrenome == "")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("O sobrenome é obrigatório");
            construir = false;
        }

        if (CPF == "")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("O CPF é obrigatório.");
            construir = false;
        }
        else if (CPF.Length != 11)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("O CPF é inválido.");
            construir = false;
        }

        if (dataNascimento == DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A data é obrigatória.");
            construir = false;
        }

        if(construir)
        {
            return new Pessoa(nome, sobrenome, CPF, dataNascimento);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Lembrese no entanto que o propósito disso é apenas didático!**

Não recomendo de forma nenhuma colocar `Console.WriteLine` dentro da classe.

Porém, como o objetivo é manter a simplicidade, não vejo problemas.

Exemplo de como consumir este método:

```
Pessoa _pessoa = Pessoa.GetInstancia("teste", "teste", "1234", DateTime.Now);

if(_pessoa != null)
{
  //Código para adicionar em uma lista.
}
```

Comment: muito obrigado, @Zorkind (sim sou novato tanto aqui no overflow quanto em programação...  resolveu meu problema... vlw mesmo xD)

Comment: Bota ai como resposta aceita ^_^ Valeu!